# QueryableStore accessible from different application id

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application which consumes as stream all user activities and I want to count for example how many times he saw the home page and so on and so forth. I materialized count into a persistent key-value store. I want to have access from a different application to this key-value store and get data from this store because I want to share these statistics via rest endpoint. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to have access from a different application to this key-value store and get data from this store because I want to share these statistics via rest endpoint. Is it possible?

Yes, this is possible. The feature is called [interactive queries](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) in Kafka Streams. There is also a demo application called [Kafka Music](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/kafka-streams-examples/docs/index.html) that you can use as a starting point.

Your first application uses Kafka Streams to compute the state continuously, and it also needs to provide sth like a REST/Thrift/... API that your second application can query. Your second application can be anything: it can be a Python app, a JavaScript app, even a command line tool like `curl` -- it doesn't have to be another Kafka Streams application.

You must manually implement the "API" of your first application with whatever REST tooling etc. you prefer using, just like for any other Java application that needs to implement a REST API. Kafka Streams provides, via the aforementioned [interactive queries](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) functionality, all the necessary methods to tap into and expose the data in your Kafka Streams state stores through the DIY API of yours. (Kafka Streams intentionally does not provide "a REST API" or "a gRPC API" etc. itself because needs across developers are often very different.)